# Small design errors

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, google-chrome

I found this little misplacing  in the new design

[image]

And that one in [deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835234/mysql-query-how-to-identify-the-syntax-error) with code blocks

[image]

Comment: The first one seems to be caused by the bounty counter, if you hide it then the line is unbroken.

Comment: The fix is to remove `line-height` from `.bounty-indicator-tab`'s styles (first issue)

Comment: Sure your browser wasn't zoomed? Ctrl-0 to reset.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek: I am sure. No zoom.

Comment: #1 will be fixed in the next push - #2 has possibly breaking-elsewhere implications I'm unsure about and have pinged Jin on. The design team is traveling to New York today so there may be a bit of a delay on that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of these should be fixed in a build rolling out in the next 7 minutes.

Comment: Fixed into a new bug. Look at the question list now. Double lines

Comment: It is really fixed now.

Comment: The bug is back

Comment: Even on the question page on the tabs `active, oldest, votes`

Comment: @juergend thanks - obviously a regression there, I pinged Jin (I'm in New York working on hardware at the moment, so can't do much)

Comment: The bug is back - again :) It was fine today until now

Comment: Now I know what it is - when I zoom in the browser to 90% then it looks weird. At 100% it is ok. My bad.