# Featured tab CSS broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just stumbled on this:

[image]

The featured tab is borked at least on Chrome latest on Mac.

Comment: I get the same behaviour with Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m and IE 9.0.8112.16421 on Windows 7

Comment: came to meta to post this. I too am having this on chrome latest windows 7

Comment: Another question like this was just deleted, but see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283957/border-under-featured-tab-is-one-pixel-off-in-firefox and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283912/small-design-errors?lq=1

Comment: that makes it a regression @Kendra.

Comment: The second link does. The first one was never addressed directly by designers.

Comment: Bounty overflow. Was just going to report the same.

Comment: Just took a screenshot and was about to post this as well. Reproduced on Firefox 35.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: @DanielA.White: the regression was already reported; in the second link.

Comment: @DanielA.White: ah, no, that was marked as fixed too. This is a regressing regression. Next up, a recursive regression!

Comment: @MartijnPieters The first link I posted is the regression report (although it only mentions Firefox) and was never addressed. I posted the links in reverse order as I felt the first link I posted was more relevant as it was never marked as fixed. Although looking at it, it looks like the break is a couple of pixels now and not just one.

Comment: @Kendra: the answer on that report states that they fixed it. The comments then go on to show it broke again, it was fixed again, and now it is broken again.

Comment: Here's the deleted question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286787/featured-tab-positioning/286812

Comment: It appears to be an issue with the blue box as the same thing happens for me on my reputation and responses tabs on my profile.

Comment: This should be all fixed now. Please let me know if you are still seeing the bug. Thanks.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Now it has disappeared.